# Azure Data Factory - read only custom role

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-rbac

We'd like to give support personnel Read Only access to Azure Data Factories so they can troubleshoot issues. Following [this guide](https://www.techtalkcorner.com/role-reader/) I was able to create a custom role that mostly does the trick but on further review I can see that the user granted this role can still add/delete/save pipelines which is a no-no for us. Any suggestions here? the template below is what we use:

```
{
  "Name": "MGB Data Factory Reader",
  "Id": "88888888-8888-8888-8888-888888888888",
  "IsCustom": true,
  "Description": "Read Only Access to Data Factories ",
  "Actions": [
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/datafactories/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/datafactories/activitywindows/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/datafactories/providers/Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/datafactories/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metricDefinitions/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/datafactories/datasets/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/datafactories/datasets/activitywindows/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/datafactories/datasets/sliceruns/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/datafactories/datasets/slices/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/datafactories/tables/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/datafactories/gateways/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/datafactories/linkedServices/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/datafactories/datapipelines/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/datafactories/datapipelines/activities/activitywindows/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/datafactories/datapipelines/activitywindows/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/datafactories/runs/loginfo/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/adfcdcs/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/adflinkconnections/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/getDataPlaneAccess/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/getFeatureValue/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/operationResults/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelineruns/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelineruns/activityruns/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelineruns/queryactivityruns/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/providers/Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metricDefinitions/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/queryFeaturesValue/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/querypipelineruns/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/querytriggerruns/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/triggerruns/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/dataflows/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/dataMappers/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/sandboxpipelineruns/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/sandboxpipelineruns/sandboxActivityRuns/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/globalParameters/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/integrationruntimes/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/integrationruntimes/getstatus/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/integrationruntimes/monitoringdata/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/integrationruntimes/nodes/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/integrationruntimes/outboundNetworkDependenciesEndpoints/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedServices/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/managedVirtualNetworks/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/managedVirtualNetworks/managedPrivateEndpoints/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/privateEndpointConnectionProxies/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/privateEndpointConnectionProxies/operationresults/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/privateEndpointConnectionProxies/operationstatuses/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/privateEndpointConnections/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/privateLinkResources/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines/pipelineruns/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines/pipelineruns/activityruns/progress/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/providers/Microsoft.Insights/logDefinitions/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/triggers/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/triggers/triggerruns/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/locations/getFeatureValue/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/checkazuredatafactorynameavailability/read",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/operations/read"
  ],
  "NotActions": [],
  "DataActions": [],
  "NotDataActions": [],
  "AssignableScopes": [
    "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId1}",
    "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId2}",
    "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/{groupId1}"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not provide the built-in reader role on the data factory resource for the user.why create a custom role

[image]

Comment: Good point. The test I conducted reader assigned Reader rights at eh Resource Group level. This test showed that users could still ad/delete pipelines but could not publish them. Are you saying that if we assign the permissions at the resource level then this would work as expected?

Comment: Hey, My understanding is irrespective of any assignment a user can add/delete/update a pipeline in his system but he/she cannot publish it/override the changes in environment. So providing the reader right on the resource is much better than granting read on entire RG. As long as someone cannot publish/execute any pipelines , it sholdnt be a concern

Answer (score 0):

After testing granting read only permissions at the resource and resource group level, the standard out of the box Reader role works fine. At first blush it seems like it's giving users access to add/delete pipelines but in reality nothing changes unless it's published, function to which read only users do not have access. Thanks for the replies.